# How to get multiple columns on subquery or group by

Tags: mysql, join, group-by, subquery

I have two tables on MySql, the first contains an **ID** and the **name** of some products. I have to get the cheapest combination of brand/market for each product. So, I've inserted some itens into both tables:

**UPDATE:** Inserted new product (bed) with no 'Product_Brand_Market' to test LEFT JOIN.
**UPDATE:** Changed some product prices for better testing.

```
CREATE TABLE Product(
   id INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
   name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL);  

CREATE TABLE Product_Brand_Market(
   product INT UNSIGNED,
   market INT UNSIGNED,   /*this will be a FOREIGN KEY*/
   brand INT UNSIGNED,    /*this will be a FOREIGN KEY*/
   price DECIMAL(10,2) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY(product, market, brand),
   CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (product) REFERENCES Product(id));

INSERT INTO Product
(name) VALUES
('Chair'),   /*will get id=1*/
('Table'),   /*will get id=2*/
('Bed');     /*will get id=3*/

INSERT INTO Product_Brand_Market
(product, market, brand, price) VALUES
(1, 1, 1, 8.00), /*cheapest chair (brand=1, market=1)*/
(1, 1, 2, 8.50),
(1, 2, 1, 9.00),
(1, 2, 2, 9.50),
(2, 1, 1, 11.50),
(2, 1, 2, 11.00),
(2, 2, 1, 10.50),
(2, 2, 2, 10.00); /*cheapest table (brand=2, market=2)*/
                  /*no entries for bed, must return null*/
```

And tried the following code to get the desired values:

**UPDATE:** Changed INNER JOIN for LEFT JOIN.

```
SELECT p.id product, MIN(pbm.price) price, pbm.brand, pbm.market
FROM Product p
LEFT JOIN Product_Brand_Market pbm
    ON p.id = pbm.product
GROUP BY p.id;
```

The returned price is OK, but I'm getting the wrong keys:

```
| product | price | brand | market |
|---------|-------|-------|--------|
| 1       | 8     | 1     | 1      |
| 2       | 10    | 1     | 1      |
| 3       | null  | null  | null   |
```

So the only way I could think to solve it is with subqueries, but I had to use two subqueries to get both brand and market:

```
SELECT
p.id product,
(
    SELECT pbm.brand
    FROM Product_Brand_Market pbm
    WHERE p.id = pbm.product
    ORDER BY pbm.price
    LIMIT 1
) as brand,
(
    SELECT pbm.market
    FROM Product_Brand_Market pbm
    WHERE p.id = pbm.product
    ORDER BY pbm.price
    LIMIT 1
) as market
FROM Product p;
```

It returns the desired table:

```
| product | brand | market |
|---------|-------|--------|
| 1       | 1     | 1      |
| 2       | 2     | 2      |
| 3       | null  | null   |
```

But I want to know if I really should use these two similar subqueries or there is a better way to do that on MySql, any ideas?

Comment: So you want the rows from `Product_Brand_Market` with the lowest price per product?

Comment: yes, the brand FK and market FK

Comment: What if you have two rows for one product with the same (lowest) price. Which one do you want to select?

Comment: I just need one row, so in this case it can be any of them.

Comment: It doesn't make sense to not grouping the non-aggregating columns.  Your code won't even run in other rbms.  When you get the MIN(price), how do the system know which brand or market to pull?

Comment: You're right @Eric, I just tried everything I could think, I'm a beginner on databases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a correlated subquery with `LIMIT 1` in the WHERE clause:

```
SELECT product, brand, market
FROM Product_Brand_Market pbm
WHERE (pbm.brand, pbm.market) = (
    SELECT pbm1.brand, pbm1.market
    FROM Product_Brand_Market pbm1
    WHERE pbm1.product = pbm.product
    ORDER BY pbm1.price ASC
    LIMIT 1
)
```

This will return only one row per product, even if there are two or many of them with the same lowest price.

Demo: http://rextester.com/UIC44628

#### Update:

To get all products even if they have no entries in the `Product_Brand_Market` table, you will need a LEFT JOIN. Note that the condition should be moved to the ON clause.

```
SELECT p.id as product, pbm.brand, pbm.market
FROM Product p
LEFT JOIN Product_Brand_Market pbm
  ON   pbm.product = p.id
  AND (pbm.brand, pbm.market) = (
    SELECT pbm1.brand, pbm1.market
    FROM Product_Brand_Market pbm1
    WHERE pbm1.product = pbm.product
    ORDER BY pbm1.price ASC
    LIMIT 1
  );
```

Demo: http://rextester.com/MGXN36725

The follwing query might make a better use of your PK for the JOIN:

```
SELECT p.id as product, pbm.brand, pbm.market
FROM Product p
LEFT JOIN Product_Brand_Market pbm
  ON (pbm.product, pbm.market, pbm.brand) = (
    SELECT pbm1.product, pbm1.market, pbm1.brand
    FROM Product_Brand_Market pbm1
    WHERE pbm1.product = p.id
    ORDER BY pbm1.price ASC
    LIMIT 1
  );
```

An index on `Product_Brand_Market(product, price)` should also help to improve the performance of the subquery.

Comment: Thanks, you really solved the problem, but I'm sorry, I did a mistake on the code, I need something like a LEFT join instead an INNER join, is there a way to return brand and market = NULL if there is no correspondent of the product on Product_Brand_Market?

Comment: PERFECT! Thank you :)